# How to find 11th derivative of $e^{-2t} \sin(1+2\sqrt{3}t)$

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble with convert $(-2 + (1+2\sqrt{3})i)$ to polar form. How do I find the angle?

Do I use the trig identities and $\sin(1+2\sqrt{3}t) = \sin(1)\cos(2\sqrt{3}t)+\cos(1)\sin(2\sqrt{3}t)$? 
Thanks

Comment: Wait, are you looking for the derivative or the conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quickly if you convert to polar coordinates.
$$e^{-2t}\sin\left(1+2\sqrt3t\right)=\Im e^{(-2+2i\sqrt3)t+i}$$
So
$$\begin{align}\frac{d^{11}}{dt^{11}}e^{(-2+2i\sqrt3)t+i}&=(-2+2i\sqrt3)^{11}e^{(-2+2i\sqrt3)t+i}\\
&=\left(4\left(-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\right)^{11}e^{(-2+2i\sqrt3)t+i}\\
&=4^{11}\left(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\right)^{11}e^{(-2+2i\sqrt3)t+i}\\
&=2^{22}e^{\frac{4\pi i}3}e^{(-2+2i\sqrt3)t+i}\\
&=2^{22}e^{(-2+2i\sqrt3)t+i+\frac{4\pi i}3}\end{align}$$
Then
$$\frac{d^{11}}{dt^{11}}e^{-2t}\sin\left(1+2\sqrt3t\right)=\Im2^{22}e^{(-2+2i\sqrt3)t+i+\frac{4\pi i}3}=2^{22}e^{-2t}\sin\left(2\sqrt3t+1+\frac{4\pi}3\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

By [Leibniz Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule):

$$\left(e^{-2t}\sin\left(1+2\sqrt3\,t\right)\right)^{(XI)}=\sum_{k=0}^{11}\binom{11}k\left(e^{-2t}\right)^{(k)}\left(\sin\left(1+2\sqrt3\,t\right)\right)^{(11-k)}$$

Using the periodicity modulo $\;4\;$ of the derivatives of sine this doesn't look so bad. For example, if you want the seventh summand above it is

$$\binom{11}7(-1)^7\,2^7\,e^{-2t}\,\left(2\sqrt3\,t\right)^4\,\sin\left(1+2\sqrt3\,t\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have to do $Im(e^{i(1+2\sqrt{3})-2t})$ now we kbow $(e^t)'=e^tdt$ so on differentiating we just get a constant thus the nth derivative is $Im(e^{n(i(1+2\sqrt{3})-2t)}).(2\sqrt{3}i-2)^n$ now can you calculate.

Answer (score 0):

i have got this here
$$-2097152\, \left( \sqrt {3}\cos \left( 1/3\,\sqrt {3} \left( 6\,t+
\sqrt {3} \right)  \right) +\sin \left( 1/3\,\sqrt {3} \left( 6\,t+
\sqrt {3} \right)  \right)  \right) {{\rm e}^{-2\,t}}
$$
why do you need such a high order of derivative?